# Smooth a curve with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I defined a curve manually and now I need to smooth it.
[image: Curve to smooth]

[image: GN generated the curve]

I try things like the GN 'Deform curves on surface' but I can't do it work.

Any idea about how can I smooth it?

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect with "smooth" you mean rounded corners. To achieve that, you can plug a *Fillet Curve* node before the *Curve to Mesh* node, set it to *Poly* and adjust the *Count* and *Radius* to your liking:

[image: curve with rounded corners]

Comment: Thanks Gordon ! It's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I am showing another way to smooth out curves that are comprised of sections.

This method involves setting the curve type to `Bezier` and setting the handles' type to `Auto`.

Keep in mind that both this method and the fillet method will give a very different result when the sections that make out the curve are sampled.
[image]